# matplotlib: specify default colors explicitly

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

When I do

```py
ax.plot(...)
ax.plot(...)
...
```

the color of each successive plot is in the [default color cycle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html) (blue, orange, green &c).

Alas, *sometimes* I need to specify the colors *explicitly* in each call to [`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) because each *logical* plot is generated by *several* such calls.

So, suppose I need to plot `num_plots` curves, and I want the color selection to be identical to the default one.

#### How do I get the list of colors that matplotlib would use if I call `ax.plot` exactly `num_plots` times?

I tried

```py
import matplotlib.cm as colormaps
colors = colormaps.get_cmap(None, num_plots)(np.linspace(0,1,num_plots))
```

(and various names like `"Accent"` and `"winter"` instead of `None` that appear in the error message when I use random junk instead of `None`).

Comment: [I think this answers your question](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html). If nothing else, you can print the object `colors` to get the hex codes: '#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf'.

Comment: @Kat: thank you, this is a good start. However, what if my `num_plots>len(colors)`?

Comment: “C0” “C1”, … are the default colorcycle, in order.

Comment: @JodyKlymak: but then if I have _many_ plots, some of them will be in the same color. I don't think this happens when I do _not_ specify the color explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correclty, but it seems like you are asking for the default color cycle which can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html). You say that

> @JodyKlymak: but then if I have many plots, some of them will be in the same color. I don't think this happens when I do not specify the color explicitly.

**This is not a correct assumption. It is a color cycle, so the colors *will* repeat.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_plots = 20
for i in range(num_plots):
    plt.plot([0,1], [(i+1)/num_plots, (i+1)/num_plots])

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to cycle through the colors manually, just get the list of default colors and use the modulo operator as follows.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
colors = prop_cycle.by_key()['color']

num_plots = 20

for i in range(num_plots):
    plt.plot([0,1], [(i+1)/num_plots, (i+1)/num_plots], color=colors[i % len(colors)])

plt.show()
```

Comment: PS: If this does not answer your question, consider updating your question to be more concise and include an image of what you want & what you are getting now.